# Meaning of somewhere off?

Tags: meaning-in-context, definition

What is the definition of "somewhere off" not just in this example but also the meaning in **general**

**Example:**

Potential infinity refers to a procedure that gets closer and closer to, but never quite reaches, an infinite end. For instance, the sequence of numbers
1, 2, 3, 4, ...
gets higher and higher, but it has no end; it never gets to infinity. Infinity is just an indication of a direction -- it's "**somewhere off** in the distance."

Comment: "somewhere off" isn't a set phrase... For example, "somewhere (off the highway)" "somewhere (over there)" "somewhere (off in the distance)" "somewhere (in the other room)". Are you trying to figure out "off in the distance" versus "in the distance"?

Comment: It is a non-specific reference to a place.  So it is in the distance and at an unspecified location.